# opencpu not working with data.table in R

Tags: javascript, r, data.table, opencpu

I am using the R package *data.table* to deal with big data files. However, I found it cannot be used with opencpu.

For example, my R function is,

```
foo <- function() {
    library(data.table)
    iris = data.table(iris)
    o = iris[,.N,Species]
    return(list(o,dim(o)))
    }
```

and I tried to *ocpu.call* this function by running,

```
  var req = ocpu.call("hello",{},
   function(session){
     console.log(session)
   });
```

And when I check the session, the result output is

```
[[1]]
Null data.table (0 rows and 0 cols)

[[2]]
[1] 0 0
```

So you can see that opencpu cannot be used with R package, *data.table*.

I wonder if this is right or I just missed something here?

Comment: I even checked http://jsfiddle.net/opencpu/7torLdk9/. It works fine there but not locally. I cannot figure out the reason..

Answer (score 0):

opencpu works by providing ajax/client access to R packages in a server's R library location, so in your custom package's NAMESPACE file, make sure these lines are there

```
export(my_custom_function_name)
import(data.table)
```

The export() line should already be in there. You should also use the explicit "data.table::data.table(example_df)" namespace syntax convention in your R functions.

I am curious myself why the import() is required (by opencpu?), but I'm new to R package development. I notice [this](https://github.com/opencpu/stocks/blob/master/NAMESPACE) public example from the opencpu public app page uses import(ggplot2). For namespaces, [this](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/namespace.html) has been helpful.